# PopUpPicker - does not conform to protocol

Tags: popup, protocols, textfield, picker

I am very new to Swift and programming in general.

I am trying to add a Pop Up Picker on a textfield and when the user selects the item from the picker, they can press OK with that item displayed in the textfield and the PopUp disappear.

I have successfully implemented this with a Pop Up Date Picker as I have used this from GutHub successfully.  I thought it would be easy to mimic this code for my Pop Up Picker which has proven to be more difficult than expected.

I have a sepeate XIB file which holds the View with the Picker and OK Button.  I then have 2 swift files one for the PopViewController and the other for the PopPicker.

Not even sure if this code is correct but the error I am getting is that my Picker does not conform to protocol.  Code is below for both files.

PopEngineViewController

```
import UIKit

protocol EnginePickerViewControllerDelegate : class {

func enginePickerVCDismissed(string: UITextField?)
}

class PopEngineViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var enginePicker: UIPickerView!
weak var delegate : EnginePickerViewControllerDelegate?

override convenience init() {

    self.init(nibName: "PopEnginePicker", bundle: nil)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    self.delegate?.enginePickerVCDismissed(nil)
}
}
```

and PopEnginePicker

```
import UIKit

public class PopEnginePicker : NSObject, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, EnginePickerViewControllerDelegate {

public typealias PopEnginePickerCallback = (forTextField : UITextField)->()

var enginePickerVC : PopEngineViewController
var popover : UIPopoverPresentationController?
var textField : UITextField!
var dataChanged : PopEnginePickerCallback?
var presented = false
var offset : CGFloat = 8.0


public init(forTextField: UITextField) {

enginePickerVC = PopEngineViewController()
self.textField = forTextField
super.init()
}

public func pick(inViewController : UIViewController, dataChanged : PopEnginePickerCallback) {


    if presented {
        return  // we are busy
    }

    enginePickerVC.delegate = self
    enginePickerVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    enginePickerVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500,208)


    popover = enginePickerVC.popoverPresentationController
    if let _popover = popover {

        _popover.sourceView = textField
        _popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.offset,textField.bounds.size.height,0,0)
        _popover.delegate = self
        self.dataChanged = dataChanged
        inViewController.presentViewController(enginePickerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        presented = true
    }


}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(PC: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {

    return .None
}

}
```

Not even sure if I am going down the complete wrong path however I want it to look like the below as I have done with the date picker as it shows in the link below:

http://coding.tabasoft.it/ios/a-simple-ios8-popdatepicker/